# Need to get to the foreign keys of an entity marked as "Deleted" for auditing

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using v1 of EF(.NET 3.5 SP1). I'm subscribing to the SavingChanges event of the ObjectContext wherein I audit deletes for a particular entity type. I need to get to the foreign keys of the entity being deleted i.e EntityKeys of the related entities (RelatedEnds) but the EntityKeys of the related entities are nulls.

Is there any way to get to the foreign keys of an entity which has been marked for deletion? 
Does EF null out the EntityKeys of all RelatedEnds for an entity which has been marked for deletion? If so, is there a way I can get hold of the foreign keys?

Comment: This is night and day different depending upon whether the related objects cascade. Do they?

Comment: They do cascade but no with the "OnDeleteCascade" turned on. I control deleting related entities in code in a partial class for each entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer on the MSDN forums.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/e4c4739f-731a-491a-a4c9-eb3c91f7c7eb